# Editor with html specific features

Tags: html, vim, phpstorm, webstorm, text-editor

I search editor/plugin for editor with such html specific features:

- remove node
- remove only node content
- navigation to next/prev node, and also parent/child node
- navigation to next/prev node attribute
- navigation between opening and closing tags

I love and use Vim and JetBrains IDEs, but I haven't found plugins with similar funcitonality for them. Can anybody suggest such editor/plugin?

Comment: I'd recommend checking out Atom (atom.io). Not sure I know of any plugins that directly do all that, thought there might be one, but its really easy to write your own plugins too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at https://github.com/mattn/emmet-vim. It seems to be fulfilling most of your requirements.

Comment: yeah, it is quite good plugin) not all functionality that I wanted, but it is better than nothing. Thanks!)

Answer (score 2):

Most of this is present by default in WebStorm / PHPStorm:

## remove node

Remove a node and all descendants with:

- move cursor into node
- `Expand Selection` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>) until the whole node is selected
- <kbd>Del</kbd>

## remove only node content

- move cursor into node content
- `Expand Selection` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>) until all content is selected
- <kbd>Del</kbd>

Remove a specific enclosing parent node with `Remove Enclosing Tag` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>)

## navigation to next/prev node, and also parent/child node

Next/previous node is `Next method` (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>↓</kbd>) / `Previous method` (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>↓</kbd>)

Jump to the start of the parent node with `Move Caret To Code Block Start` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd>), and to the end with `Move Caret To Code Block End` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd>). May have to press that twice, depending on where the cursor was.

*(I don't see a good way to jump directly to child nodes)*

## navigation to next/prev node attribute

*(would like to know one for this too!)*

## navigation between opening and closing tags

Just like moving to parent node above: `Move Caret To Code Block Start` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd>), and `Move Caret To Code Block End` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd>).